Why does David 'praise word' in both Elohim and Jehovah?
Literal, see Biblehub, from Psalm 56:10 :

In God I will praise word. In Yahweh I will praise word.

'Word' here is dabar דָבָר Strong 1697 used 1,440 times in the Hebrew Old Testament (a significant number if that number is accepted to be correct, 12x12x10) and appears to be a broad concept, sometimes being translated 'thing' or 'matter' as well as 'word' or 'words'.
Why does David 'praise word' in Elohim and in Jehovah ?

There are two different questions here. Dottard has answered the first one already, so perhaps the second should be removed from the last line and submitted as a separate question (I see it as the more interesting question and would like to see an answer to it.)

@RayButterworth I do not accept that David wrote a 'meaningless' statement. I am asking about the word 'word' - its meaning and the grammar associated with it.

Yes agreed, but I would also be interested in what it means to praise anything to the two names separately in pre-christian times. If you don't want to post that question, let me know and I will.

@RayButterworth I am assuming the meaning will open up here, myself.

And I'm hoping they don't; it really is a different question. (So I've asked it: hebrew - In Psalms 56:10, why does David address "God" and "Jehohvah" separately?

In the context of Psalm 56, the psalmist calls out to God for help against his enemies. Amid his cries for help are expressions of trust in God and praise for His word. In v.4, a close connection is seen between the trust that the psalmist places in God and the praise of His word.
Psalm 56:4 YLT

In God I praise His word, in God I have trusted, I fear not what flesh
doth to me.

In v.10, “word” appears again in two parallel statements, similar to the one in v.4, but  in the absolute state without a pronominal suffix. Although the definite article is added in YLT below, it is not present in the Hebrew (interlinear).
Psalm 56:10

In God I praise the word
In Jehovah I praise the word.

According to Keil and Delitzsch, because “word” is named “absolutely,” it should therefore be understood as referencing the divine word. The lack of an article here is understood to make the noun more definite, not less (think of it in terms of a proper noun).
Keil and Delitzsch commentary

Through Elohim, Psalm 56:11 continues, will I praise דּבר: thus
absolutely is the word named; it is therefore the divine word, just
like בּר in Psalm 2:12, the Son absolutely, therefore the divine Son.

The OP asks, “Why does David 'praise word' in Elohim and in Jehovah?” Without delving into the meaning of the specific terminology, a clear association is made here as nowhere else between “word” and each of these titles/names of God. Despite the distinctions created by the different terminology, the construction of the statements in v.10 creates a sense of oneness -  between Elohim and Jehovah, and between “word” and each of those terms. Depending on one’s theology, the implications are of enormous significance for those who seek to better understand and praise the “word”.

@NigelJ - With regard to the implication, I am thinking in particular of Jn 1:1. The discussion here, I think, has significant bearing on the meaning of "the Word is God".

Indeed. The wording stood out to me when singing it the other morning. Up-voted +1.  I see 'Elohim' and 'Jehovah' at the burning bush and I see the 'Angel of the Lord' associated with both. And, here, I see 'Elohim' and 'Jehovah' and I see 'word' associated with both. And I see the concepts of dabar in Hebrew and logos in Koine Greek having a strong connection and overlap.

Revelation 19:13 also strengthens the connection between dabar and logos.

Indeed. Agreed.

As it sits, the Hebrew of Ps 56:10 is almost meaningless and there appears to be an implied pronoun missing - either:

In God, whose word I praise, in the LORD, whose word I praise

or

In God I will praise His word, In the LORD I will praise His word

in either case the sense appears to be:

I praise God for what he has promised; yes, I praise the LORD for what he has promised.

That is, David appears to be praising God the revelation of God that He had thus far revealed.  This is a regular theme in the Psalms such as:

Ps 119:16 - I will delight in your statutes; I will not forget your word.
Ps 119:49 - Remember Your word to Your servant, upon which You have given me hope.
Ps 119:81 - My soul longs for your salvation; I hope in your word.
Ps 119:105 - Your word is a lamp to my feet and a light to my path.
Ps 119:40 - Your word is very pure; Therefore Your servant loves it.
Ps 119:160 - The sum of your word is truth, and every one of your righteous rules endures forever.
Ps 119:172 - My tongue sings of Your word, for all Your commandments are righteous.
Ps 138:2 - I bow down toward your holy temple and give thanks to your name for your steadfast love and your faithfulness, for you have exalted above all things your name and your word.
etc (there are many many more)


Then the question becomes : Why did David omit the possessive pronoun rendering the statement (in your words) 'meaningless' and, I would add, ambiguous ? Is it rather not the case that there is a meaning to the actual words that we are given ?

By saying there is a pronoun 'missing' are you suggesting that there is an issue with the accuracy of the Hebrew text that we have before us ?

And why both 'Elohim' and 'Jehovah' ?

@NigelJ - This is an example of synthetic parallelism, a common practice in biblical poetry, where the author says the same thing in two different ways.

@NigelJ no? Why would you assume David is who omitted the possessives here?

@DanFefferman I don't  believe in that doctrine. That is an excuse made by those who will not admit that they lack the spirituality to interpret the subtlety of the two similar concepts. Scripture is resoundingly compact and never wordy. If it is said in two different ways then there is a spiritual reason for the (supposed) repetition. I am seeking the reason for the two statements being made. There is nothing whatsoever 'synthetic' about the word of God.

@AviAvraham I am not suggesting that anyone omitted anything. If someone suggests it, then I query that suggestion.

@NigelJ I would hate to think of myself as making excuses or  lacking the spirituality to interpret two supposedly different concepts. For me, both Elohim and Yahweh refer to God in this case.  When I have more leisure I may create answer that defends the poetic parallelism hypothesis.

@NigelJ - You question, as my answer makes clear, strongly suggests that the "word" is that of god/YHWH, else what "word" are we discussing" - my word, your word, words generally, whose word?  That is why I suggested the implied missing possessive pronoun of some sort as most modern versions, including the KJV, have it.  further, as you would be aware, Hebrew often contains implied (tacit) words such as the verb to be, and pronouns.

@Dottard I believe I understand the point you are making in regard to language but it is my experience (in faith) that there is a spirituality to be seen, here. 'The words that I have spoken to you ; they are spirit and they are life' conveys a depth deeper than human language associated with the actual words on the page. Praising 'word' in 'Elohim' suggests something very deep to myself. It is that which I am pursuing. Nor is it just out of intellectual speculation. I feel there is something here, not to be missed.

@NigelJ - then you are venturing on thin ice because only God is worthy of praise and worship.  If the "word' is not God's word, (as most versions suggest) then we arrive at a deep theological conundrum - why praise any word except that of Jehovah's?

@Dottard . . . . . .  unless dabar is a concept similar to logos . . . . . . .

@NigelJ - the Hebrew "dabar" and Greek "logos" do have very similar meanings.  However, this they have as a difference - "Logos" is used as a title of Jesus in John 1:1-3, 14, Rev 19:13; however, as best I can determine, "dabar" is never used as a title of God unless in this single verse, which is dubious.

I would say that logos is an aspect of deity, rather than a title. And it is not beyond the bounds of possibility that dabar may bear the same potential in this verse : in my own view. Which would be the reason for the dual statement.

Regarding the use of Elohim and Yahweh, there are varying opinions but Jewish commentators usually understand Elohim to refer of God's actions or attributes, while YHWH refers to God's essence or being.
The Babylonian Talmud (Berakhot 60b:9) relates the "word" in Elohim to goodness, and the "word" in Yahweh to God's part in human suffering:

The Gemara explains that "In God, I will praise His word;" that is the
revelation of God’s attribute of benevolence, while: "In the Lord, I
will praise His word;" that is the attribute of suffering; even if God
brings suffering to bear upon me, I will still praise Him.

But Rashi, following the Jerusalem Talmud rather than the Babylonian version cited above, sees the two "words" as signifying God's justice and mercy, respectively:

For the
Divine standard of justice and for the Divine standard of mercy I will
praise.

Turning to Christian commentators we are no closer to consensus:
Barnes

Whether I contemplate God in the usual name by which he is known -
אלהים 'Elohiym - or by that more sacred name which he has assumed -
יהוה Yahweh - that which seems now to me to lay the foundation of
loftiest praise and most hearty thanksgiving, is that he has spoken to
people, and made known his will in his revealed truth.

Gill cites one of the Jewish interpretations mentioned above:

"In the Lord will I praise his word": in the former clause the word
"Elohim" is made use of, which, the Jews say, denotes the property of
justice, and in the latter Jehovah, which with them is the property of
mercy; and accordingly the Targum paraphrases the words.

Cambridge introduces the hypothesis of poetic parallelism:

The line is repeated for emphasis
with the substitution of the covenant name Jehovah for God. The two
names sometimes occur together in the Elohistic Psalms (e. g. Psalm
55:16; Psalm 58:6); and a refrain is not always repeated in precisely
the same form.

The verses cited by Cambridge are particularly useful in this context:

But I will call upon God,
and the Lord will save me. (55:16)
O God, smash the teeth in their mouths;
break the fangs of these lions, Lord! (58:6)

That these are poetic reiterations seems clear. Elohim is not different deity than Yahweh. Whether there is also a deeper meaning to the poet's use of Elohim in one verse and Yahweh in the next, is another matter.
Conclusion: It is possible to interpret "God" and "Lord" as referring to various aspects of the Deity, such as justice and mercy. This makes good sense with 55:16, but not with 58:6. The OP's verse (56:10) does not contain enough information to say either way. Neither does it lend itself clearly to "Elohim" as referring to God's attributes and "Yahweh" to God's essence. In the end the OP's question is a matter of theological speculation or spiritual insight. We can reach no firm conclusion based on hermeneutics alone.

There are distinctions in the use of 'Elohim' and 'Jehovah' firstly in the two creation accounts which demonstrate their relative meanings and also in the use of 'Jehovah' in regard to Israel and the sending of Moses, then again at the burning bush where the activity of the two names is apparent. Summing up, there is clear evidence in scripture as to the revelation given in regard to these two descriptive names applied to Deity by the utterance of the Holy Spirit. Thus in the Psalm under consideration we can perceive that God in both aspects is being considered.

I would agree it can be interpreted as you say, but I do not agree that the evidence is clear. It relies on human insight, which may be correct or not. As I showed above, experts -both rabbinical and Christian- have varying understandings, including that these are simply two names for the same thing, like God and  the Deity.

Indeed. And I understand that 'Elohim' would be 'Deity' (a collective noun) and 'Jehovah' would be 'God' (an identifier). And 'praising word' would have slightly different connotations in regard to each of the two. Yes, I agree.
